# My readline variable is not changing from strip()

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, readline, strip

My program is supposed to:

1) Read a line (.readline() function) from a text file

2) Place it in a variable in the Python program

3) Use the .strip() function to strip the line of text of anything that's not a letter

4) Place it in a dictionary.

I then print the content of the dictionary.

However, when I send the readline variable to the .strip() function and print the dictionary, nothing is stripped.
Please tell me what I am doing wrong or missing.

```
dict = {}

with open ('Text for Read from File.txt') as linefile:

    readfile = linefile.readline()

    readfile = str(readfile)

    readfile = readfile.strip()

    dict[readfile] =+ 1

print(dict)
```

This is what prints:

```
{'/a/abbey/sun_aqswjsnjlrfzzhiz.jpg\n': 1}
```

This is the line from the text file, but all of the slashes and periods are supposed to be stripped.

Comment: What is `readfile.strip('a')` supposed to do? It strips the `'a'` character, but why are you using it?

Comment: Beware: `dict[readfile] =+ 1` is `dict[readfile] = (+1)`, not `dict[readfile] += 1`. Use `collections.Counter` if you want to count the number of occurrences of each line.

Comment: @ForceBru Sorry about that. I put that in there to see if maybe the strip function was supposed to have something specific to strip, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

`.strip('a')` will strip the character `"a"` from either the left or right of the string. Stripping all non-alphabetic characters you could do one of the following:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> re.sub('^[^a-z]+|[^a-z]+$', '', s)
'a/abbey/sun_aqswjsnjlrfzzhiz.jpg'
>>>
>>> ''.join(re.findall('(?<!^)[^a-z]+(?!$)|[a-z]+', s))
'a/abbey/sun_aqswjsnjlrfzzhiz.jpg'
```